# Duplicating strchr()

Tags: c, arrays, string, pointers

I am pretty new to C, as I am only taking it as an introductory course, and I am having issues with a homework problem. The goal of the program is to pass an array name of type string and a dynamically chosen character from a loop to a function. The function must check the string for the chosen character and if found return a pointer to the character in the string. If the character is not found then a NULL pointer is supposed to be returned. My code gets stuck in an infinite loop on the first character of the string...

```
#include<stdio.h>

char occur(char array[],char c);

int main(void){
    char array[]="Hello World!";
    int i = 33;
    char c;
    char occurence;

    for(i=33;i<=126;i++){
        c = i;
        occurence=occur(array,c);
        printf("%c\n",occurence);
    }

    return 0;
}

char occur(char array[], char c){
    int i = 0;
    char *temp=array;

    for(temp=array+i;*temp!='\0';i++){
        if(c==array[i]){
            return *temp;
        }
        else{}
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Please, please indent your code!

Comment: I'm still rather new to this but I will try my best in the future!

Comment: Yeah, it is a lot harder than it needs to be :)

Answer (score 0):

use

```
for(temp=array; *temp!='\0'; temp++){
   if(c==*temp) {
   ...
```

Comment: Ahh. That is now printing semi-correct. Now I just need to not print so many white spaces.

Comment: Dang it you beat me! ;)

Answer (score 0):

Make your for statement like so:

```
for (char* temp = array; *temp != '\0'; temp++) {
    if (*temp == c) {
        return temp;
    }
}
```

Then remove the first two lines.
I will explain what is wrong with your function. In the line:

```
for(temp=array+i;*temp!='\0';i++){
```

The `temp=array+i` part is only run once, so the value of temp never changes, even though `i` does. In my example, first `temp` is set to `array`, hence the part:

```
... char* temp = array; ...
```

`temp` points to the next `char` each loop:

```
... temp++ ...
```

And the loops stop if it sees a null character:

```
... *temp != '\0' ...
```

There you go!

Comment: Thanks! That's what I ended up doing. It just took me a second to realize it.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to Pan Ruochen my code now runs correctly. Here it is:

```
#include<stdio.h>
char occur(char array[],char c);
int main(void){
    char array[]="Hello World!";
    int i = 33;
    char c;
    char occurence;
    for(i=33;i<=126;i++){
        c = i;
        occurence=occur(array,c);
        if(occurence==0){}
        else{
            printf("%c\n",occurence);
        }}
    return 0;
}
char occur(char array[], char c){
    char *temp=array;
    for(temp=array;*temp!='\0';temp++){
        if(c==*temp){
        return *temp;
        }
    else{}
    }
return 0;
}
```

Comment: Just as a note, it is traditional to see `p` used as a pointer, rather than `temp`. (e.g. `char *p = array;` and `for (; *p; p++)` is the same thing you are doing with `for(temp=array;*temp!='\0';temp++)`. Also, note, you can pass `array` as `char occur (char *array, char c)`. Nothing wrong with the array syntax (e.g. `occur (char array[], ...`, but the practical effect when an array is passed as a function parameter, it is converted to a pointer.